# How to capture a stringified text "2,000.00" in bytes without the "," and convert it to float64?

Tags: regex, go

My goal is to capture a stringified text "2,000.00" in `[]byte` without the `,` and convert it to `float64`. The problem is the regex captures Group `MUTASI` with the `,`

The code

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    mutasis := [][]byte{[]byte("28,000.00 DB"), []byte("5,000,000.00")}
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^(?P<MUTASI>[\d,.]+)(?: (?P<TIPE>DB|CR))*$`)
    matches := re.FindAllSubmatch(bytes.Join(mutasis, []byte("\n")), -1)
    for _, match := range matches {
        fmt.Println(string(match[1]))
    }
}
```

What I've did:

1. use `^(\d+(?:[,\d|.\d]+)*)$` but apparently, `?:` is overriden by the brackets `( )`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```golang
func toFloat(data []byte) (float, error) {
    return strconv.ParseFloat(strings.ReplaceAll(string(data), ",", ""), 64)
}
```

Split your original byte array by space, then pass it to this function. It will return either the float you need or error

Comment: Is it possible to do this with just regex?

Comment: @kidfrom No, it is not.